# Loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: xcode, view, nib

First, I've checked the other questions and none of them have provided a solution to my problem.

I have a custom UITableViewCell which I am trying to load and use in a UITableView. This was working fine under the previous version of Xcode but yesterday, I finally updated to the latest version (4.51 4G1004). After I did this I now get the error message

> ```
> loaded the "TemplateView" nib but the view outlet was not set.
> ```

The view is a custom class that is a descendant of `UITableViewCell`, but I also tried to create a new NIB that was a straight UITableViewCell and got the same error. I tried `Cleaning` the app to see if that would correct it but it did not.

Any help would be appreciated as this one is really bugging me and I'm not sure what direction to turn at this point.

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to correct this I created a new class and started to re-build both the UITableView and the UITableViewCell and step by step I was able to get this close to working. When adding an action to one of the buttons in the cell I got an error message and decided to back that part of the code out. I'm still getting the following error.

[Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key addOrEditSections.']

The "addOrEditSections" method was completely pulled out of the code and is no where in my project. Is this just a really buggy version of XCode? I tried "cleaning", I restarted Xcode but I still get this error even though no where in the code is it calling for "addOrEditSections".

Comment: Okay - fixed this problem (missed left over outlet connection in nib). To get around the original problem I recreated the classes for the UITableView and the class and nib for the UITableViewCell and it is now working. Now, when I try to navigate further, I am once again getting the "loaded nib but the view outlet was not set" error. Did the upgrade to XCode corrupt the nibs in this project? I can get by this by re-building from scratch and thankfully, this is a new project so there aren't a lot of nibs, but this seems like a bug in the upgrade to Xcode!